# Setting button tint on radio button programmatically

Tags: android, radio-button

I want to set a radio button tint programmatically. in xml there is an attribute called "buttonTint" to do the work. but in program I am not able to find any method to set tint or color to the radio button. is there any method or any ways to do that?

```
 <RadioButton
    android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Payeer" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**`setButtonTintList (ColorStateList tint)`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setButtonTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList))

> Applies a tint to the button drawable. Does not modify the current tint mode, which is SRC_IN by default.
>
> Subsequent calls to `setButtonDrawable(Drawable)` will automatically mutate the drawable and apply the specified tint and tint mode using `setTintList(ColorStateList)`.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RadioButton radioButton;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        radioButton = findViewById(R.id.radioButton);

        ColorStateList myColorStateList = new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{
                        new int[]{getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)}
                },
                new int[]{getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent)}
        );

        radioButton.setButtonTintList(myColorStateList);

    }


}
```

Comment: thank you brother. it is working. but it is requiring minimum API (LOLLIPOP). is it going to crash if the version of the running phone lower than LOLLIPOP?

Comment: @SorwarHossainMostafa *`is it going to crash if the version of the running phone lower than LOLLIPOP`*  the answer is **NO**

Answer (score 5):

Based on both previous answer one line code for setting background color is

**Java code**

```
button.setButtonTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getColor(R.color.red)));
```

**Kotlin code**

```
button.buttonTintList=ColorStateList.valueOf(getColor(R.color.red))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Below Code:

```
button.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(resources.getColor(R.id.red)));
```